# ¿Cómo puedo optimizar este proceso con : BackgoundWorker C#?

Tags: c#, hilos, eventos, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Realicé un proceso que hace transferencia de datos a la BD y debe ejecutarse en segundo plano, de modo que el usuario pueda pausar el proceso o cancelarlo en el momento que desee.

Lo hice usando la herramienta que proporciona Visual Studio C# 
 "BackgoundWorker", de esta forma funciona, pero quiero optimizarlo (Mejorarlo) :

**¿Cómo puedo mejorar este proceso, hay un mejor método?**

En el evento **DoWork del BackgoundWorker** tengo lo siguiente:

```
private void corriendo_proceso(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Cuando se preciona en detener vuelve esta valor verdadero.
        if (pausar_proceso == true)
        {
            //Este ciclo es quien pausa el proceso hasta que el usuario responda Si o NO
            while (pausar_proceso == true)
            {
                //Cuando el ussuario no desea cancelar y preciona que NO
                if (pausar_proceso == false)
                {
                    break; //Rompe el ciclo While
                }

                //Cuando el usaurio Cancela y preciona que SI
                if (proceso_segundo_plano.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;  
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else //Continuar el proceso...
        {
            Thread.Sleep(0010); //Tiempo de espera. 

            //Ejecuta todo el proceso y tareas de segundo plano....
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException excepcion)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error en el proceso. \n\nDetalles del error: \n\n" + excepcion.Message,
                                    "AVISO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    return;
}
```

En el evento **RunWorkerCompleted:**

```
private void proceso_completo(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Error != null)
      {
          //Mensaje de Error.
      }
      else
      {
          if (e.Cancelled) //Si se cancelo el proceso.
          {
              if (pausado == true)
              {
                  //Mensaje de espera. 
                  pausado = false;
              }
              else
              {
                  //Mensaje de Cancelado.
              }
          }
          else
          {
              //Mensaje de Completado
          }
      }
      return;
}
```

En el evento **ProgressChanged:**

```
private void progreso_proceso(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
      // Modificar objetos que son creados en otro hilo.
      // y para disparar un evento en este metodo para notificar a otros metodos o clases
      //....
      return;
}
```

**Botón que ejecuta el proceso:**

```
private void boton_ejecutar_proceso_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       //Inicializando valores de las variables.
       pausar_proceso = false;

       //Ininicializar los eventos.
       proceso_segundo_plano = null;
       proceso_segundo_plano = new BackgroundWorker();
       proceso_segundo_plano.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
       proceso_segundo_plano.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
       proceso_segundo_plano.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(corriendo_proceso);
       proceso_segundo_plano.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(progreso_proceso);
       proceso_segundo_plano.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(proceso_completo);

       //Invocar el proceso.
       proceso_segundo_plano.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

**Botón Detener el proceso:**

```
private void boton_detener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (proceso_segundo_plano.IsBusy)
      {
         //Mensaje Esperando por el usuario. 

         pausar_proceso = true; // esto activará el evento de "Dowork" para hacer un bucle que
         //que comprueba si el valor de "pausar_proceso" está falso

         DialogResult resultado;
         resultado = MessageBox.Show("¿Esta seguro que desea detener el Proceso?", "DETENER", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
         if (resultado == DialogResult.Yes)
         {
             pausar_proceso = true;
             cancelado = true;
             proceso_segundo_plano.CancelAsync();

             //Proceso Cancelado.
         }
         else
         {
             //Continuar con el proceso...

             pausar_proceso = false; //si el usuario hace clic en NO continuará el proceso.
             return;
         }
     }
}
```

> Anteriormente lo hice usando "ThreadStart", pero Visual Studio me mostró excepciones
>   de que el método está obsoleto.
>
> ThreadStart delegado = new ThreadStart(CorrerProceso);
>
> Thread hilo = new Thread(delegado);
>
> hilo.Start();
>
> hilo.Resume();
>
> hilo.Pause();
>
> hilo.Abort();

**NOTA:** no tengo mucha experiencia realizando procesos en segundo plano.

Comment: Deberias leer sobre Await y TASK.. que tipo de cosas hace tu proceso en segundo plano?

Comment: @gbianchi el proceso prácticamente se trata de transferencias de datos. mientras esta transfiriendo un conjunto de datos a la BD, el usuario puede pausar o cancelar.

Comment: Entonces deberias usar await y task definitivamente. Thread ha quedado obsoleto (sigue funcionando, pero hay formas mejores de hacerlo). Te sugiero que leas respecto de eso, y si tenes alguna duda consultes.

Comment: De esta forma no me sale que esta obsoleto pero cuando usé `ThreadStart si saltó la excepción de obsoleto` . ***No tengo idea de como usar:  Await y TASK* pero investigaré al respecto.

Comment: @gbianchi puedes proporcionarme un ejemplo aunque no sea completo de como poder realizar el código de mi publicación usando: **TASK**  ?

Comment: en un rato trato de construirte algo que tambien involucre suspend y continue

Comment: @gbianchi, ok quedo a la espera de esa información. Me sería de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Escribi un codigo rudimentario que demuestra el uso de `await` / `Task` con una UI no bloqueada.

Algunos extractos del codigo (por ejemplo el token de pausa) estan tomados de otros lugares. Al final estan las referecias de lo que corresponde.

El codigo completo esta en [GitHub](https://github.com/topcatarg/PruebaAwaitTask). Aca voy a explicar solamente las partes importantes.

(La prueba incluye un paquete nuget mahapps, es para usar el control de espera y que se note que pasa algo en la pantalla).

Await es el operador que se usa para ejecutar llamadas asincronicas, mientras que la clase Task se usa para definir los metodos a ejecutar asyncronicamente.

Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente proceso

```
private async Task<bool> Prueba1()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(10000));
    return true;
}
```

Este proceso es asyncronico, y ejecuta una llamada a sleep, que no hace mas que dormir un thread, que por las caracteristicas de Task.Run, es un thread hijo.

```
private async void Test1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
....
    bool b = await Prueba1();
....
}
```

Este metodo es el evento click de un boton. fue definido como async porque el compilador obliga a agregar dicha informacion a los eventos cuando van a hacer uso de una llamada `await`. `await Prueba1()` Se ejecuta asyncronicamente, eso quiere decir que no va a bloquear la UI (todavia se puede mover la pantalla sin problema) y espera a que el proceso llamado termine para continuar con la ejecucion del boton. Esto es asi porque el compilador arma una maquina de estados para que funcione.

Para generar un efecto cancelar y/o suspender y resumir, hay que complicar un poco mas el codigo:

```
private async Task<bool> ProcesoMuyLargo(PauseToken EstaPausado)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await EstaPausado.WaitWhilePausedAsync();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (source.IsCancellationRequested)
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Este proceso, admite cancelaciones y suspensiones. El token de suspension esta copiado de este [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2013/01/13/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods/)

El token de cancelacion es el original de la clase CancellationToken.

```
private async void Test2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = source.Token;
    SourcePausa = new PauseTokenSource();
    PauseToken tokenpausa = SourcePausa.Token;
    bool b = await Task.Run(() => ProcesoMuyLargo(tokenpausa), token);
}
```

Este proceso ejecuta la funcion descripta anteriormente. Sin embargo, la misma puede ser cancelada ejecutando:

```
source.Cancel();
```

o suspendida/resumida usando:

```
SourcePausa.IsPaused = true;
SourcePausa.IsPaused = false;
```

Estos objetos estan definidos a nivel de clase como:

```
CancellationTokenSource source;
PauseTokenSource SourcePausa;
```

Comment: Excelente aporte, una pregunta más: **Si se desea modificar un  objeto que no pertenece al hilo principal se puede hacer sin la necesidad de usar Delegados?**  Esto lo digo porque, cuando se usa `ThreadStart` si se intenta modificar un objeto que no pertenece al hilo desde donde se ejecuta salta una excepción al igual con el `BackgoundWorker` si NO hacen los cambios desde el Evento: `ProgressChanged` igual salta la excepción de que no se pueden modificar objetos que pertenecen a otro hilo, y para resolverlo los invoco a través del uso de Delegados.

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, estoy intentando declarar: `private async void` y no me reconoce la palabra reservada **async** ,  y también  `RoutedEventArgs` tengo los espacios de nombres: `System.Threading  y  System.Threading.Tasks`, este tipo de método solo esta disponible para **WPF** ?

Comment: Respecto del ejemplo de actualizar otro thread, dejame armarte algo.  Async esta declarado en c# 4. Probaste bajar el proyecto en github para verlo como ejemplo?

Comment: Si es usando Delegado se como hacerlo, tengo un método para hacer esas invocaciones y modificar objetos de otros hilos, y con respecto a `github` si lo descargué pero solo puedo verlo en modo código, no puedo cargar el proyecto estoy en el trabajo y la versión de VS aquí es 2010 el proyecto es incompatible, **Lo probaré en casa.**

Comment: Te has aventado tremenda respuesta. Sin duda el señor Skeet estaría muy orgulloso :D