# ¿Es posible que un subproceso acabe con el proceso padre?

Tags: c#, hilos

El problema es el siguiente.

Tengo un hilo que conecta con un Telnet, el problema es que a veces el telnet se queda trabado, o se pierde la conexión momentaneamente y el programa que conecto con el telnet queda apuntando a la nada.

El problema este lo trato de forma de que, haya un hilo padre, que se ocupe de reiniciar el hilo hijo cada 30 minutos.

```
while (true)
        {
            /*
             * Bucle que reinstancia el hilo, reiniciándolo para que cada X tiempo 
             * se relance el servicio sin importar como esté. 
             */

            error=false;

            try
            {
                ThreadStart consola = new ThreadStart(telnetListener);
                Thread thread = new Thread(consola);
                thread.Start();

                Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 30);
                thread.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log("FALLO" + e.Message);
                error = true;
            }
```

La jerarquía es la siguiente.

```
Hilo padre
   |
   |Hilo hijo
      |
      | Escuchamos los mensajes que llegan de Telnet
```

Entonces lo que me falla es que en el programa me salta una excepción en el hilo hijo, guardo la excepcion en un log y me dice "subproceso anulado"

Y no sé como solucionarlo .

Comment: Haría falta ver como esta el "telnetListener", pero a priori yo creo que es ahi donde debes gestionar la excepción. Por otro lado,en el catch pones error= true, pero luego no haces nada con ello, ya que en la siguiente iteración del bucle lo pones a false?

Comment: Ah,y como siempre, siempre digo: **no utiliceis la clase `Thread`!** Esta cerca de ser obsoleta, y es muy compleja en su manejo cuando hay alternativas mas comodas como `BackgroundWorker` o `Task-Async/Await`

Comment: @Pikoh agradecería muchísimo que me echaras un cable por el chat para preguntarte las dudas que tengo con Tasks, background worker lo desconozco.

Comment: fijate si esta respuesta te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/125788/324

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: @fredyfx no, no conseguí solucionarlo.

Comment: Pudiste solucionarlo ?

Comment: No sera que el telnet esta lanzado una excepcion? Puedes mostrar el stacktrace de la excepcion?

Comment: Puede utilizar un Timer y que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo y dispara el evento y ahí reinicias todo.
Otra opcion es usar una Task con token de cancelacion.

Comment: He incluido una repuesta al problema planteado en tu pregunta, creo que debe funcionar en tu caso, en las pruebas que hice funciona satisfactoriamente, te recomiendo implementarlo y probarlo. @fredyfx

Comment: gracias bro @EduardoReyes que los éxitos te acompañen, gracias por dar solución a una pregunta que lleva buen tiempo :D

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, estamos en el sitio para colaborar, ya me es estimulante saber que te ha servido mi respuesta; soy nuevo en el sitio y además, desarrollador autodidacta, me seria de gran estimulo que si lo consideras justo, seleccionaras mi respuesta como correcta y la puntearas.

Comment: Podrías sustituir el Sleep con ``.Join(1000*60*30)`` esperas a que termine o de el tiempo de espera. El Join retorna true si finalizó o false si dio tiempo de espera y haces el Abort.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error debe estar en que intentas abortar `thread.Abort();` un `thread` que ya se ha detenido por una razón relacionada con los procesos que ejecuta, no se puede intentar abortar un proceso que ya no existe, además cuando mandas a abortar el `thread`, solo a partir de un tiempo de espera fijo, puede que lo estés abortando en algún momento en que se encuentra corriendo satisfactoriamente.
Yo en ese caso haría lo siguiente:
Declarar e iniciar el `thread` fuera del `while`, crear una variable `TimeSpan` que sera el tiempo a esperar para verificar si el `thread`sigue en ejecución, cuando no se cumpla la condición del `while` retornar atrás y volver a crear e iniciar el `thread`.

```
  //Se crea el delegado ThreadStart
  ThreadStart consola = new ThreadStart(telnetListener);
  //Se declara y arranca el Thread en su primer inicio
  Thread thread = new Thread(consola);
  thread.Start();

  TimeSpan waitTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); 

//Punto de retorno para reiniciar el Thread     
Reiniciar:
  //Verificar el estado del Thread
  if (thread.ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.Running)
  {
     try
     {
        //Se crea nueva instancia y se reinicia el Thread
        thread = new Thread(consola);
        thread.Start();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
       log("FALLO" + e.Message);
     }
   }
   //Esta condición permite reiniciar el Thread solo si no está vivo
   while (thread.IsAlive)
   {
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
   }
    //Retornar al punto de reinicio
    goto Reiniciar;
```

Te recomiendo implementar y probar este código.

Answer (score -2):

Quizas podría funcionar declarar el thread fuera del while, asi controlas el inicio y el abortar de la misma instancia tal como ya lo haces:

```
   ThreadStart consola = new ThreadStart(telnetListener);
   thread = new Thread(consola);

    while (true)
    {
        /*
         * Bucle que reinstancia el hilo, reiniciándolo para que cada X tiempo 
         * se relance el servicio sin importar como esté. 
         */

        error=false;

        try
        {
                          thread.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 30);
            thread.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log("FALLO" + e.Message);
            error = true;
        }
```