# Error al llamar async task en evento load de winforms c#

Tags: c#

Tengo una aplicación en C# que al desplegar cierta ventana realiza varias operaciones en su metodo Load(), como son varias tareas se demora cierto tiempo y he intentado ponerle una animación de carga pero no he podido, e intentado poner el metodo Load() del formulario asincrono pero sigue sin funcionar, mi metodo load es este:

```
private async void FormMembresia_LoadAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pcloader.Visible = true;
        await DescNodoLoading();
        pcloader.Visible = false;
    }
```

Desde aquí llamo al método DescNodoLoading() que es el que ejecuta las tareas (Consultar en una API, archivos locales y por ultimo graficar) , es un método de esta forma:

```
private Task<Boolean> DescNodoLoading()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
             //CODE
            }
         }
       }
```

Al abrir la ventana no termina de cargar al 100% y se bloquea hasta que acaba la tarea del método DescNodoLoading(), incluso ni siquiera muestra el gif de carga porque se bloquea hasta que culmina el método, ¿alguien podría decirme porque no se ejecuta la función en segundo plano mientras se crea el formulario y me muestra el gif de carga que es lo que creo debería pasar?

Comment: El segundo metodo no es asincronico. Fijate si esta respuesta que di hace tiempo no te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/125913/324

Comment: He cambiado el segundo metodo a la forma: ` private async Task<Boolean> DescNodoLoading()` Pero se mantiene el comportamiento, no deja que acabe de cargarse la ventana y muestre el gif mientras hace el subproceso en segundo plano.

Comment: Aca habria que revisar bien, porque tu metodo esta dentro del loading.. por lo cual justamente se ejecuta ese metodo asincronicamente.. o sea.. no va a terminar ese metodo hasta que no se cumplan las tareas que pediste.. si vos queres que siga.. deberias sacar el await de ahi.. o hacer con un task.run y va a seguir ejecutando codigo como si nada..

Comment: Existe forma de ejecutar el metodo justo despues que el form haya cargado? soy nuevo en C# y no se si exista algun evento que se dispare luego de que haya sido cargado el form y asi poder ejecutar mi metodo.

Comment: Si. Shown. Te convendria ver este link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes cambiar a esto:

```
private Task<Boolean> DescNodoLoading()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
         //CODE
     }
   }
```

BeginInvoke lo que hace es ejecutar codigo en el hilo de la UI, con lo cual no es asincrono

Comment: Pero si no coloco BeginInvoke no puedo modificar los elementos del formulario, ya que lo hagado desde un hilo diferente al de la UI.

Comment: He sacado el segmento de codigo que modificaba la UI y ahora si ha funcionado al eliminar BeginInvoke, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si ocupas actualizar la UI hay formas de hacerlo desde un método asincrono, pero no debes hacerlo con begininvoke.

Answer (score -1):

El problema es en sí que esa es la labor del `Await`, si quieres que se ejecute en segundo plano debes usar `Async`, te explico:

- [Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh156528(v=vs.120)): El operador await se aplica a una tarea en un método asincrónico para suspender la ejecución del método hasta que se complete la tarea esperada.
- [Async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh156513(v=vs.120)): Use el modificador async para especificar que un método, una expresión lambda o un método anónimo es asincrónico. Si se utiliza este modificador en un método o una expresión, se hace referencia al mismo como método asincrónico.

Estos son los principales tipos de [programación asíncrona](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh191443(v=vs.120)) de C#.

Comment: No me permite cambiar await por async,  cambie mi segundo metodo por: ` private async Task<Boolean> DescNodoLoading()` Pero se mantiene el comportamiento, no deja que acabe de cargarse la ventana y muestre el gif mientras hace el subproceso en segundo plano.

Comment: Tu problema es que usas begininvoke, ni idea de porqué lo haces pero no es necesario para traeas asíncronas. Ahora, si lo que va dentro del Task.Run tiene código de la UI, entonces tienes un problema, estás mezclado código asincrono con acceso a la UI