# Para trabajar con programacion asincrona, ¿necesito una conexion asincrona?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, windows-forms, asincronismo

Buen día amigos estoy viendo algunos tutoriales sobre el manejo de programación asíncrona con .net, en windows form.. muchos muestran conceptos y practicas básicas de como implementarlo.

Pero mi dudas es. cuando queremos trabajar con persistencias de datos, ya sea con Bases de datos. tendría que realizar una conexión asíncrona?

Estoy viendo la documentación con un micro orm llamado dapper. y revisando algunos de sus metodos, algunos tienen implementado por defecto esa parte.

por ejemplo. 
Esta es la forma de trabajar de modo sincrono

```
var result = VariablesGlobales.GlobalConnection.Query("SELECT * FROM ...").firstOrDefault();
```

Resulta que hay otra funcion similar pero agregando Async en su metodo para poder diferenciarlos.

```
var result = await VariablesGlobales.GlobalConnection.QueryAsync("SELECT * FROM ...");
```

Mi conexion podria decirse que es una declaración global de esta.
en una clase estatica.

```
public static class VariablesGlobales
    {
        private static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection _GlobalConnection;
        public static String UsuarioNombre { get; set; }
        public static String EmpresaNombre { get; set; }
        public static String SucursalNombre { get; set; }
        public static int UsuarioID { get; set; }
        public static int EmpresaID { get; set; }
        public static int SucursalID { get; set; }
        public static int RolID { get; set; }
        public static string Rol { get; set; }
        // TIEMPO DE EJECUCION DE LA APLICACION, Y BLOQUEO EN TIEMPO DE INACTIVIDAD

        public static int Horas { get; set; }

        public static int Minutos { get; set; }


        public static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection GlobalConnection
        {
            get
            {
                _GlobalConnection = _GlobalConnection ?? new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);
                return _GlobalConnection;
            }

            set
            {
                _GlobalConnection = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Ahora trabajando con el ExecuteAsync.. y realizando las operaciones básicas en una Base de datos.

Es necesario una conexión asíncrona?.
si es así, como podría implementarla?

Gracias.

Comment: Que quiere decir una conexion asincronica?

Comment: Puede ser que estes confundiendo conceptos? las conexiones a la base de datos siempre son sincronicas, la forma de hacer la llamada a tu procedimiento y esperar la respuesta es asincronica

Comment: Bueno, aun no estoy tan seguro, con lo que me acabas de decir, crei que para trabajar con funciones asíncronas, necesitaba una conexion igual. pero con lo que acabas de decir. que una conexion siempre es sincrona. ya empiezo deducir que no necesito una.}

Comment: Los que es asincronica, es la llamada a la funcion. Dapper llama a una funcion asincronica, que se conecta a la db, baja los datos, y despues cuando termina reanuda la ejecucion. Pero la llamada a la DB, es sincronico dentro de su thread asincronico.

Comment: Si no tenes claro el concepto de sincronismo, fijate esta respuesta a ver si te aclara un poco mas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/125913/324

Comment: Lo revisare....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En winform te beneficiarias del trabajo `asincrono` sino quieres bloquear el thread de la UI para por ejemplo mostrar un `progress bar` o algun icono que refleje que la app esta trabajando
Si lo haces de forma `sincrona` el thread de la UI se bloquea y la app parece esta congelada, es aqui donde se usa la clase Thread o el BackgroundWorker, pero si puede aplicar `async/await` es mucho mejor.

Por lo general, aplicar esta tecnica se observa en desarrollo web, ya que requiere resolver varias peticiones de request que no se bloqueen.

Comment: Hola Leandro, parece un comentario. Quizá deberias ponerlo como tal y si el usuario confirma la necesidad de background workers, ampliar la informacion del comentario con ejemplos de codigo y oportuna explicacion. Un saludo