# C# esperar a que termine un hilo sin bloquear la UI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hilos

estoy intentando ejecutar una funcion de una clase a través de un hilo en c# al presionar un botón. El codigo de mi form es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ServicioJuicios
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PerformanceCounter counterCPU;
    bool abierto = false;
    int i = 0;
    waitDialog wd;
    Thread cpu;
    JuiciosController jc = new JuiciosController();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        counterCPU = new PerformanceCounter();
        counterCPU.CategoryName = "Processor";
        counterCPU.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        counterCPU.InstanceName = "_Total";
    }

    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Equals("") || textBox2.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario o contraseña no especificado");
            return;
        }
        this.label2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))));
        this.label2.Text = "Servicio en Ejecucion";
        abierto = true;
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (abierto)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new Action(setLabels));
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }

        });
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void setLabels()
    {
        jc.controller(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, this);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))));
        this.label2.Text = "Servicio Detenido";
        abierto = false;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cpu = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(cpuUsage));
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        cpu.IsBackground = true;
        cpu.Start();
    }

    private void cpuUsage()
    {
        lblStatus.Text = counterCPU.NextValue() + "%";
    }
}
}
```

La aplicacion es algo sencilla, por ahora muestra el uso del cpu, pero quiero que al presionar el button2 el thread que se ve en el codigo se ejecute en segundo plano mientras se sigue actualizando el uso del cpu, pero el proceso bloquea todo y no consigo hacer que el form no se bloquee.
Ya lo intenté con Task y tampoco me funcionó. Tambien puse IsBackground = true pero no hizo nada. La funcion Join me pega igual el programa.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda y guia para lo que requiero.

Comment: Dime si [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/125913/324) no responde tu pregunta.

Comment: completamente amigo, era lo que estaba buscando, muchisimas gracias