# Pausar BackGroundWorker

Tags: c#, hilos, backgroundworker

Estoy intentando pausar la ejecucion del hilo del BGW, he mirado por SO ingles y SOes y no comprendo como hacerlo. Mi codigo es este:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PruebaWork
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void funcionCancelar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }
    //enviar
    private void funcionEnviar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
    //doWork
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 10);
        }
    }
    //challenged
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Se acabo");
    }
}
```

}

Hace la ejecucion del for en segundo plano, eso funciona, y por lo que he leido, para pararlo, se hace con _busy.set() y _busy.reset (llevo poco en c# aun no entiendo lo que significa _) y he probado algunos codigos, pero no termino de entenderlo, si alguien me pudiera poner un ejemplo con algo de explicacion, lo agradeceria.

Comment: Dale un vistazo a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/125788/69447), puede ayudarte....

Answer (score 1):

Mi recomendación es que no siga intentando detener el hilo manualmente puesto que ya tuve una experiencia y casi me vuelvo loco tratando de hacer lo que usted quiere. En mi caso lo solucione dejando ese trabajo a C# haciendo uso del using. De esa forma el método DoWork se ejecuta una sola vez y el solo se hace dispose como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
private  void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var worker=new BackgroundWorker())
        {
            worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;

            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Esto se ejecuta y hace un Dispose() al terminar");
    }
```

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu respuesta. Gracias.