# Backgroundworker C#, no se ejecuta

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Estoy intentado ejecutar una función que me toma unos 10 segundos pero para que no piensen que se crasheo, puse un ProgressBar, pero ahora quise ponerlo en un proceso en segundo plano y solo muestre el progressBar pero no ejecuta la funcion.

```
public bool InsertBack()
        {
            try
            {
                return Insert();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TareaTerminada = false;
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private bool Insert()
        {
            OrdenesDeTrabajo OT = new OrdenesDeTrabajo();
            TareaTerminada = false;

            OT.DescontarInventario(_Articulo, txtCantidad.Text, IdOrden);
            OT.Guardar(IdOrden, txtCantidad.Text);

            TareaTerminada = true;

            return TareaTerminada;

        }
```

esto el que me regresa el valor, los procesos los tengo en una clase aparte

Luego los eventos de BackgroundWorker

```
public void IniciarOperacionAsincrona()
        {
            GrabarDatos();
        }

        public void CancelOperacionAsincrona()
        {
            if (worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
            {
                worker.CancelAsync();
            }
        }

        private void GrabarDatos()
        {
            if (worker == null)
            {
                worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

                //declaramos los eventos del Backgroundworker
                worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
                worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
                worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

     worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

            // Aquí es donde se inicia el proceso
            // Aquí se tiene que llamar al proceso que ocupa mucho tiempo
            void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                e.Result = Insert();
            }

            // Este evento sirve para actualizar una barra de progreso
            void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            {

            }

            // Se dispara Cuando se termina el proceso en segundo plano
            void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Cancelled == true)
                {
                    AccionEscribeEnBarraEstado("¡Cancelado por el usuario!");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (e.Error != null)
                    {
                        AccionEscribeEnBarraEstado("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AccionEscribeEnBarraEstado("Terminado - AccionBotonSaveBackgroundWorker");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Cuando mando llamar a la funcion lo hago por medio de un boton

```
 private void BtnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCantidad.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Favor de Capturar la cantida de articulos", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPersonal.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Favor de Seleccionar un Adorno Terminado", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtArticulo.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Seleccionar un Adorno", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                timer();
                IniciarOperacionAsincrona();
                OrdenesDeTrabajo();

                //limpiamos todos los textbox
                ClaseGeneral CG = new ClaseGeneral();
                CG.Limpiar(this);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Donde estas ejecutando el worker? si queres una solucion con Async/task (mas moderna), hay una pregunta al respecto que hace exactamente esto...

Comment: tengo un boton (ya lo agregue al codigo)... si pudieras mandarme la pregunta para darle una pasada estaria bien

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/125788/324, es mas, capaz la respuesta a tu pregunta esta alli tambien.. no veo donde inicias el worker aca

Comment: En la parte del codigo del boton, hay una funcion llamada "IniciarOperacionAsicrona() dentro de esta funcion esta el worker.RunWorkerAsync", le dare una vuelta muchas gracias!

Comment: Ok se ve que copiaste mal el codigo, porque no la encuentro por ningun lado esa llamada

Comment: Cierto... no lo vi

Comment: Sobre que plataforma estas trabajando?