# En un método ASYNC el await no funciona c#

Tags: c#, asynctask, async-await

Estoy intentando que aparezca un nuevo Window y hasta que el usuario no le loguee  no se cierre la pantalla. El problema es que el "await" no espera , de tal manera que la pantalla se crea y se cierra al instante.

Aquí genero el hilo :

```
public async Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options, CancellationToken cancToken)
    {
        _options = options;

        var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(cargarWindow));

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();           
        thread.Join();


        return this.result;
    }
```

Y aquí genero la pantalla con el await:

```
 public async void cargarWindow()
    {
        var window = new Window
        {
            Width = 900,
            Height = 625,
            Title = "Login"
        };  

        var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();

        var signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

        this.result = new BrowserResult()
        {
            ResultType = BrowserResultType.UserCancel
        };

        webBrowser.Navigating += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (BrowserIsNavigatingToRedirectUri(e.Uri))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;

                var responseData = "";


                {
                    responseData = GetResponseDataFromFormPostPage(webBrowser);
                }


                this.result = new BrowserResult()
                {
                    ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success,
                    Response = responseData
                };

                signal.Release();

                window.Close();
            }
        };

        window.Closing += (s, e) =>
        {              
            signal.Release();
        };

        window.Content = webBrowser;
        window.Show();           
        webBrowser.Source = new Uri(_options.StartUrl);

        await signal.WaitAsync();


    }
```

En el " await signal.WaitAsync();" es donde debería parar pero se sale del hilo.

La creación de la pantalla y el logueo ya la probé individualmente y funcionaba sin tener que crear ningún hilo  , pero al meterlo dentro de la aplicación me daba un error de que tenia que añadir el "ApartmentState.STA" , y desde que metí el hilo ya no hacia la espera en el "await"

Llevo con esto varios días y no consigo solucionarlo.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabo de solucionar el problema.

He quitado el **`await`** y he utilizado las opciones que ofrece los **`Thread`**, en este caso:

```
// En el show()
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
```

Y

```
// Dentro del window.closing   
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
```

Comment: Probablemente me llamen el cansino que siempre va en contra de `Thread`, pero te recomiendo de verdad que no lo uses. `Task` es mucho mas sencillo de manejar y mas seguro. [Jon Skeet approves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13429164) :)

Comment: @Pikoh Acabo de probar a utilizar un Task y a quitar el Thread pero me da error de que necesito ApartmentState.STA a la hora de crear el Window.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esta excelente respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/125913/15301) de @gbianchi a ver si te da una pista de como usar task correctamente

Comment: De todas maneras, todas las operaciones que tengan que ver con el UI deben ir en el hilo principal, no en un hilo. Es posible que por eso te esté dando ese error.