# Llamar a una función asíncrona en C# y capturar el resultado

Tags: c#, vb.net

hace unos días comencé a indagar C# y que vengo de muchos años de vb6. Y me resulta bastante diferente por cierto.
El tema es que estoy tratando de llamar a una función que me devuelva un bool y esta es asíncrona y si bien este método que pongo en la captura me funciona no se como capturar el valor devuelto.
Gracias por su apoyo!

```
 private async void btLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await this.ControlLogin("miguel","12345");

    }



    async Task<bool> ControlLogin(string name, string pass)
    {
        Query Qref = database.Collection("users").WhereEqualTo("username", name).WhereEqualTo("userpass", pass);

        QuerySnapshot snap = await Qref.GetSnapshotAsync();

        foreach (DocumentSnapshot docsnap in snap)
        {
            Users user = docsnap.ConvertTo<Users>();

            if (docsnap.Exists)            

                return true;              

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Lee aca para mas info: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/125913/324

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo tienes que signar el resultado a una variable boleana y listo:

```
bool exitoso = await this.ControlLogin("miguel","12345");
if(exitoso)
{
 // codigo
}

// mas codigo..
```

Comment: pero a visto te dije q recien empiezo y esta sintaxis me es nueva. Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

Te falta la asignacion a la variable booleana donde deberias capturar el valor devuelto.

```
private async void btLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  bool retorno = await this.ControlLogin("miguel","12345");
}

async Task<bool> ControlLogin(string name, string pass)
{
    Query Qref = database.Collection("users").WhereEqualTo("username", name).WhereEqualTo("userpass", pass);

    QuerySnapshot snap = await Qref.GetSnapshotAsync();

    foreach (DocumentSnapshot docsnap in snap)
    {
        Users user = docsnap.ConvertTo<Users>();

        if (docsnap.Exists)            

            return true;              

    }
    return false;
}
```