# No se muestra el progreso de la barra en C# - ProgressBar y BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#

Tengo una Barra de Progreso pero no funciona. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias de antemano.
Saludos.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace SigcFlc.REPORTES
{
public partial class RpteFaenamientoPorcino : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

    public RpteFaenamientoPorcino()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
    }

    private void RpteFaenamientoPorcino_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void BtnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void GenerarReporte()
    {
        // PROCESO....
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        GenerarReporte();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        LblPorcentaje.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
        if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            MessageBox.Show("Terminado");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Que te hace exactamente? No te muestra nada ni hace ninguna función cuando le das al botón aceptar?

Comment: Hola. El proceso (GenerarReporte) correo normalmente pero no se refleja nada en la Barra de Progreso. Gracias

Comment: si queres una solucion con await/task (mas moderna) mira aca: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125788/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-optimizar-este-proceso-con-backgoundworker-c/125913#125913

Comment: Te ejecuta el MessageBox.show("terminado")?

Comment: No, nada. De frente aparece el Reporte en pantalla

Comment: Disculpa sí sale "Terminado" después del reporte en pantalla. Pero en la Barra no se ve nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te figura el messageBox terminado es que te está realizando el trabajo demasiado rápido e inmediatamente se reinicia a 0. Prueba a utilizar el evento RunWorkerCompleted del siguiente modo para abstraer el reinicio del progressBar.value a 0, de este modo primero deberías visualizar el 100 % completado, el messageBox("terminado") y luego reiniciarse, si no prueba a quitar el reninicio a 0 del progressBar a ver que es lo que te muestra por pantalla

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace SigcFlc.REPORTES
{
public partial class RpteFaenamientoPorcino : Form
{

BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

public RpteFaenamientoPorcino()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_completed:
}

private void RpteFaenamientoPorcino_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

private void BtnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void GenerarReporte()
{
    // PROCESO....
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    GenerarReporte();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    LblPorcentaje.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";

}


 private void backgroundWorker1_completed(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
 {

   MessageBox.Show("Terminado");
   progressBar1.Value = 0;
 }


} 
}
```

Comment: Excelente mourazo. Gracias !   A tu solucion le añadi:   var porc = (decimal)reg / (decimal)ListaDetFacturadosBenef.Count * 100M;
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(porc));   ya que son varios procesos dentro de GenerarReporte().