# Evitar que la pantalla se quede cargando mientras se ejucuta un bucle

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo un bucle:

```
Thread x = new Thread(() =>
        {
            _controller = new IpCamController("http://X.X.X.X", "user", "pass");
            _controller.ImageReady += dec_FrameReady;
            _controller.StartProcessing();
        });
        x.Start();
        
        
        string ParamList;
        WaveOut _waveOut = new WaveOut();
        //WaveFileReader reader;
        try
        {
            ParamList = "http://X.X.X.X/axis-cgi/audio/receive.cgi";
            NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(ParamList);
            request.Credentials = networkCredential;
            HttpWebResponse response;
            Stream streamResponse = null;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            IWaveProvider reader;
            BufferedWaveProvider provider;
            WaveIn wi;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                //SoundPlayer y = new SoundPlayer(ms);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (streamResponse.CanRead == true)
                {
                    // 1048576 => 1MB
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
                    while (true)
                    {

                        int countBytes = streamResponse.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (countBytes <= 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("La lectura ha sido completada.");
                            streamResponse.Dispose();
                        }

                        byte[] decoded = new byte[buffer.Length * 2];
                        //Decodifica los bytes obtenidos
                        ALawDecoder.ALawDecode(buffer, out decoded);

                        wi = new WaveIn();
                        wi.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 2);
                        provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(wi.WaveFormat);
                        provider.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;
                        provider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        _waveOut.Init(provider);
                        _waveOut.Play();


                    }
                }

            }
        }

        catch (Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(es.ToString(), "\nError Message");
        }
```

Cuando el bucle se ejecuta la pantalla no carga hasta que el bucle termine, como puedo hacer que el bucle siga ejecutandose y que los demas procesos sigan funcionando con normalidad. Me explico... Se ejecuta el bucle `while(true)` hasta que el no termine, el pedazo de codigo que esta encima de el no se ejecuta(o sea el hilo), me gustaria que todo se ejecutara sin tener que esperar que el bucle termine de ejecutarse.

En conclusion: LA PANTALLA SE QUEDA CARGANDO SIN EJECUTAR LOS DEMAS PROCESOS.

EL PROCESO QUE HACE QUE TARDE MUCHO ES:

`int countBytes = streamResponse.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`

Comment: Busca información sobre procesos, multihilo, threads... En tu lenguaje. El código que tengas dentro del bucle es (aprox) lo que tendrás que hacer en el proceso hijo.

Comment: Ya trate de ponerlo dentro de un Thread y no puedo por que comparte datos de fuera del Thread que cambian 10 veces por segundos.

Comment: Vas a tener que aprender a programar con hilos y esto involucra delegados, no hay de otra forma para que la pantalla fluya sin congelarse

Comment: Si, pense en eso, pero es muy tedioso y queria ver si hay una forma mas simple.

Comment: Tal vez esto pueda ayudarte??? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125788/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-optimizar-este-proceso-con-backgoundworker-c/125913#125913

Comment: Es sencillo pero aportas poca informacion sobre tu codigo para poder ayudarte a reorganizarlo.

Comment: @RamiroBarone ahi puse mi codigo; me dolieron esos menos dos puntos, man.

Comment: te vote positivo, para volver a colocarlos. Supongo que tenes el codigo dentro de un metodo o evento de boton. Pero te voy a colocar todo dentro de una tarea, eso se va ejecutar en otro hilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modo de ejemplo lo volque a consola al proyecto, de esta forma podes ejecutar de forma asincronica, Te reordene el codigo un poco y use `using` para que se libere la memoria en cuanto terminas de usarlo. En cuanto a `try` `catch` tenias dos anidados y en el `finally` hacias todo el proceso si tu servicio te respondia, pero tenia mucho codigo y no tenia seguridad ahi en el finally, si algo fallaba rompia tu app.

El `while` no entiendo en que momento lo haces terminar y para que necesitas que este infinito.

En cuanto al metodo que demora, ese metodo tambien lo podes usar `async` y de esa forma te lo marque.

En el `if` `CanRead`, lo tenias `if(streamResponse.CanRead==true)`, lo cual no es necesario porque si el valor es `true` entra y sino sigue de largo. No hace falta la comparación.

```
    public static main(params x)
    {
        Thread x = new Thread(() =>
        {
            _controller = new IpCamController("http://X.X.X.X", "user", "pass");
            _controller.ImageReady += dec_FrameReady;
            _controller.StartProcessing();
        });
        x.Start();

        Task.Run(() => Execute());
    }

    private async void Execute()
    {
        string ParamList;
        WaveOut _waveOut = new WaveOut();
        //WaveFileReader reader;
        HttpWebResponse response;
        Stream streamResponse = null;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        IWaveProvider reader;
        BufferedWaveProvider provider;
        WaveIn wi;

        try
        {
            ParamList = "http://X.X.X.X/axis-cgi/audio/receive.cgi";
            NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(ParamList);
            request.Credentials = networkCredential;

            using (response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    //SoundPlayer y = new SoundPlayer(ms);
                    if (streamResponse.CanRead)
                    {
                        // 1048576 => 1MB
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
                        while (true)
                        {
                            int countBytes = await streamResponse.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            if (countBytes <= 0)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("La lectura ha sido completada.");
                                streamResponse.Dispose();
                            }

                            byte[] decoded = new byte[buffer.Length * 2];
                            //Decodifica los bytes obtenidos
                            ALawDecoder.ALawDecode(buffer, out decoded);

                            wi = new WaveIn();
                            wi.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 2);
                            provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(wi.WaveFormat);
                            provider.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;
                            provider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                            _waveOut.Init(provider);
                            _waveOut.Play();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(es.ToString(), "\nError Message");
        }
    }
```