# Detener código SendKeys

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes a todos,

Tengo el siguiente código, que lee un DGV y envía ciertos datos de este DGV a la aplicación externa que le pase como parámetro.

El problema es que tengo otro botón "Stop" con el cual pretendo que el usuario detenga el envió de datos a la aplicación externa si este así lo decide, pero una vez que comienza a enviar los parámetros haciendo uso de SendKeys, la aplicación no se detiene intento presionar el botón Stop, pero no hace el clic, intente también agregando una variable booleana para si el mouse entra a las dimensiones del formulario este se detenga, pero tampoco lo he conseguido.

Tengo que esperar a que termine de recorrer todo el DGV o entrar directo al IDE y parar la ejecución del código.

Este es el código que inicia el proceso, los parámetros que copio del DGV hacia la aplicacion externa, son nPart y OutVal, los demás métodos son envió de teclas o clic's del Mouse:

La aplicación externa solo recibe los valores en la misma pantalla, pero diferentes controles.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        press = true;
        try
        {
            string app;
            app = cmbSelectApp.Text;

            int hWnd = FindWindow(null, app);
            if (hWnd > 0) //If found an action
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow r in DGVLCodes.Rows)
                {
                    if (vsalir)
                    {
                        break;
                    } 

                    int idCod = 0;
                    String nPart;
                    String ColName;
                    String OutVal;
                    String Status;
                    int idApp = 0;
                    int x = 0;
                    int y = 0;
                    String Event;
                    

                    idCod = Convert.ToInt32(DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                    nPart = DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    ColName = DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    OutVal = DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                    Status = DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    idApp = Convert.ToInt32(DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                    x = Convert.ToInt32(DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                    y = Convert.ToInt32(DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                    Event = DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[8].Value.ToString();

                    switch (DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[8].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        case "MouseLeft":
                                Thread.Sleep(2500);
                                SetCursorPos(x, y);
                                clickMouseLeft();
                            break;

                        case "MouseRight":
                                Thread.Sleep(2500);
                                SetCursorPos(x, y);
                                clickMouseRight();
                                break;

                        case "Ctrl+a":
                                Thread.Sleep(2500);
                                SetCursorPos(x, y);
                                SelAll();
                                break;

                        case "Ctrl+c":

                                Thread.Sleep(2500);
                                SetCursorPos(x, y);
                                Copy();
                                break;

                        case "Ctrl+v":

                            Thread.Sleep(2500);
                            SetCursorPos(x, y);
                            Clipboard.Clear();
                            if (OutVal.Trim().Equals("Init"))
                            {
                                Clipboard.SetText(nPart.Trim());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Clipboard.SetText(OutVal.Trim());
                            }
                                Paste();
                            break;

                        case "DeleteText":
                                Thread.Sleep(2500);
                                SetCursorPos(x, y);
                                Dele();
                            break;

                        case "TAB":
                                Thread.Sleep(2500);
                                SetCursorPos(x, y);
                                Tab();
                            break;

                        default:
                            MessageBox.Show("Invalid action", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Has been susced process", "Finish process", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else //Not Found
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Window not Found!", "Open Window", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("MouseLeft not execute", "Error MouseLeft" + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Intente con una variable booleana, si se ejecuta el proceso entonces, entras a el formulario a detener el proceso.

```
 bool vsalir=false;
 bool press = false;

private void FormStartRobot_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (press)
        {
            vsalir = true;
        }
        
    }

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vsalir = true;
    }
```

**Agregado:**
Métodos que invoca en Case, mientras lee el DGV:

```
private void clickMouseLeft()
    {
        try
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("MouseLeft not execute","Error MouseLeft",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void clickMouseRight()
    {
        try
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("MouseRight not execute", "Error MouseRight", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void SelAll()
    {
        try
        {
            SendKeys.Send("^a");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Paste not execute", "Error Ctrl+a", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void Copy()
    {
        try
        {
            SendKeys.Send("^c");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Paste not execute", "Error Ctrl+c", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void Paste()
    {
        try
        {
            SendKeys.Send("^v");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Paste not execute", "Error Paste", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void Tab()
    {
        try
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Paste not execute", "Error TAB", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void Dele()
    {
        try
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{DELETE}");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Paste not execute", "Error Delete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Entonces, como puedo detener la ejecución del código, con el botón Stop?

Espero me puedan ayudar de antemano gracias.

DS

Comment: para tu rescate, deberias escribir todo lo que haces como codigo asincronico, de tal forma que tus pantallas y otros eventos se puedan ejecutar mientras haces el envio respectivo...

Comment: He agregado el resto de código, métodos que llama el case y sus instrucciones que este debe ejecutar.
Solo tengo dos botones en mi formulario y el DGV que recorro y de este envió valores a la aplicación externa con el Case, la aplicacion externa recibe valores en la misma pantalla. @gbianchi

Comment: a ver si esta respuesta que di hace tiempo te sirve... https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/125913/324... tu probema es que todo proceso bloquea la UI....

Comment: Gracias me ha servido tu respuesta. @gbianchi

Comment: la cerramos como duplicada de esa? o queres agregar una respuesta?

Comment: Como duplicada de la que diste en el otro hilo.@gbianchi