# Abrir Hilo desde Timer

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando con windows forms y tengo dos timer que abren ejecutan procesos cada 2 segundos, deseo abrir uno de esos procesos en un hilo aparte para evitar bloqueos, lo he hecho de la siguente manera

```
private void timer1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Thread Hilo = new Thread(CargaDeDatos);
      Hilo.Start();
      Hilo.Join();
}
```

Todo me funciona, pero quiero saber si es correcto abrir hilos desde un Timer, ¿esto me puede acarrear problemas de ejecución o rendimiento? ¿conocen una mejor forma de hacer?

Comment: Considera utilizar [async / await](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: mira a ver si te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/125913/324

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez  Muchas gracias

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias, esta muy buena la explicación lo probare