# Uso de una barra de progreso mientras se crea una copia de seguridad en CSV de una base de datos en WindowsForms .NET 5 (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-forms, progressbar, .net-5

Tengo lo siguientes métodos que, poco a poco, a partir de una base de datos me crean una copia de seguridad de las tablas en archivos CSV:

```
    private void CrearCopiaLectores()
    {
        var lstLectores = db.Lectores.Where(l => l.Borrado == 0);
        FileStream file = new FileStream(txtRutaCarpeta.Text + "\\"
            + NombreGeneralDir + "\\" + "lectores_bkp.csv", FileMode.CreateNew);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8);
        sw.WriteLine(UtilidadesCSV.CABECERA_PRESIDENTES_LECTORES);
        foreach (var lector in lstLectores)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(lector.Nombre + "," + lector.Apellidos);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }

    private void CrearCopiaPresidentes()
    {
        var lstLectores = db.Presidentes.Where(l => l.Borrado == 0);
        FileStream file = new FileStream(txtRutaCarpeta.Text + "\\"
            + NombreGeneralDir + "\\" + "presidentes_bkp.csv", FileMode.CreateNew);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8);
        sw.WriteLine(UtilidadesCSV.CABECERA_PRESIDENTES_LECTORES);
        foreach (var lector in lstLectores)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(lector.Nombre + "," + lector.Apellidos);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }

    private void CrearDirectorioCopia()
    {
        NombreGeneralDir = "GestorConfBackup " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy - hh.mm.ss");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(txtRutaCarpeta.Text + "\\" + NombreGeneralDir);
    }
```

Lo que ocurre es que en la parte inferior del formulario tengo una `progressBar` que me gustaría ir incrementando conforme cada método se va efectuando. Es decir, teniendo esos tres métodos que se efectúan cada vez que se realiza una copia de seguridad, me gustaría que cuando se ejecute un método se incremente un 33% hasta llegar al 100% de la barra cuando se hayan completado todos. Se que hay que utilizar tareas y creo que también hilos, pero desconozco mucho acerca de ese tema. Es que si lo hago de otra forma, la `progressBar` no avanza hasta que se completan los tres métodos, y como uno de ellos se alargue, parece que no está avanzando. ¿Qué podría hacer?

Comment: Fijate si [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125788/cómo-puedo-optimizar-este-proceso-con-backgoundworker-c) te da una idea de por donde debes ir. Si no, mas tarde te escribo una respuesta con una UI que actualiza un progress bar con tasks.

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi!! Lo he estado mirando un poco, y por lo que entiendo esos métodos tengo que hacerlos Tasks y llamarlos al hacer click en el botón, ¿puede ser? Buff... ya lo siento pero en cuanto a tareas y procesos, y como relacionarlos con la progress bar soy un poco nulo... Ya me perdonarás... Gracias aun y todo por la respuesta!!!

Answer (score 1):

No tienes que crear hilos para lo que necesitas, la manera mas sencilla es simplemente setear las propiedades Maximum y Step del progressBar

```
progressBar.Maximum = 100; // Valor máximo del ProgressBar
progressBar.Step = 34; // Cantidad en que se incrementará el valor del ProgressBar en cada llamada a PerformStep
```

y al finalizar cada método llamas al método PerformStep del progressBar

```
progressBar.PerformStep();
```

Si necesitas que se vaya incrementando mas frecuentemente, puedes establecer un valor diferente de step y buscar alguna forma de llamar el PerformStep mientras vas en cierto porcentaje de proceso del archivo.

Comment: Gracias!! Lo que pasa es que si lo hago así, se me queda atascada y avanza de golpe, solo cuando la ejecución del método acaba. Pero lo que yo quiero es que avance paso a paso.

Comment: Te refieres a que avanza de golpe al 100%? puede ser que necesites agregar `Application.DoEvents();` después de cada llamada al PerformStep(), o te refieres a que avanza de golpe hasta el 33%? si es así, tienes que tu mismo desarrollar una manera de medir el progreso para ir aumentando el valor del progressBar de acuerdo a lo que necesites, por ejemplo, obtener el conteo total de lstLectores, dividirlo en 33 y poner un contador dentro del foreach, entonces cada que tu contador aumente el numero que te dio la división, aumentas en 1 el progressBar.Value.

Comment: Lo que me ocurre es que me avanza de golpe hasta el 100%? Se queda parada y cuando acaba de ejecutar el método, se llena hasta el 100%, pero yo quiero que sea progresivo. Que cuando le diga `PerformStep()` me avance, no todo de golpe.

Comment: Probaste agregar `Application.DoEvents()` despues de `PerformStep()`? y no te funciono? verificaste que progressBar.Step no este en 100?

Comment: Buenas @Hansel Ch, perdóname por responder tan tarde, pero es que he andado muy liado y he tenido que dejar todo estancado. En realidad is me funciona, pero la barra de progreso no avanza de manera fluida sino de golpe, al final lo solucioné con el backgroundWorker. Cuando tenga un hueco, publicaré la solución. Muchas gracias, de todas formas!!