# ¿Cómo utilizar un progressbar diseñado en un form diferente?

Tags: vb.net, hilos, progressbar, backgroundworker

compañeros.
Alguien podría explicarme como puedo usar un progressBar diseñado en otro Form?
E visto muchos videos en Youtube y no logro comprender como utilizar este control, los videos que e visto muestran el progressbar dentro del mismo formulario y no desde otro form.
Te muestran como poner a correr la carga por medio de for, for each etc.. pero no veo que  expliquen una tarea real como cargar una ventana con contenido, o cuando esperas la respuesta del servidor, cuando exportas datos...

1. Modulo donde está el código de exportación a excel:

   ```
   Public RutaArchivo As String
   Public CantidadRegistros As Integer
   Public RegistrosTerminados As Integer

   Sub GenerarReporte(ByVal NombreDataGrid As DataGridView, 
   TamañoLetra As Integer, NombreDefaultReporte As String)

   'Se debe instalar el paquete Nuguet SpreadsheetLight y hacer 
   'referencia a DocumentFormat.OpenXML

   Dim Sl As New SLDocument
   Dim Columna As DataGridViewColumn
   Dim iCol As Integer = 1
   Dim iRow As Integer = 2

   'Se define el tamaño de la letra para el encabezado de las 
   'columnas y ponerle negrilla
   Dim Estilo As New SLStyle
   Estilo.Font.FontSize = TamañoLetra
   Estilo.SetFontColor(Color.DimGray)
   Estilo.Font.Bold = True
   '_____________________________________________________________

   For Each Columna In NombreDataGrid.Columns

       Sl.SetCellValue(1, iCol, Columna.HeaderText.ToString())
       Sl.SetCellStyle(1, iCol, Estilo)
       iCol = iCol + 1
   Next

   For Each Row In NombreDataGrid.Rows
       CantidadRegistros = NombreDataGrid.Rows.Count
       Dim ColumnaInicial As Integer = 1
       Dim CantidadColumnas As Integer = 
       NombreDataGrid.ColumnCount

       For i As Integer = 0 To CantidadColumnas Step 1
           Sl.SetCellValue(iRow, ColumnaInicial, 
       Row.Cells(i).Value.ToString())
           ColumnaInicial = ColumnaInicial + 1
       Next
       iRow = iRow + 1
       RegistrosTerminados = iRow

   Next

   Dim SaveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog

   SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = " *.xlsx"
   SaveFileDialog1.FileName = NombreDefaultReporte
   SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Archivos de Excel (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
   SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

   Sl.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)

   End Sub
   ```
2. Botón de Exportar

   ```
   Private Sub BtnExportar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
    Handles BtnExportar.Click
       If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy <> True Then

         BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

       End If

   End Sub
   ```
3. Evento DoWork de mi BackgroundWorker, es aqui donde le llamo la
   funcion generar reporte, pero antes de llamarla llamo a mi barra de
   progreso personalizada FrmBarraProgreso.

   [image: Esta es mi barra de progreso]

   **Dim FechaHoy As Date = Date.Now**

   **Dim F As String = Format(CDate(FechaHoy), "dd-MM-yyyy ( HH 'Hrs'
   mm 'Min' ss 'Seg' )")**

   **GenerarReporte(DgvEmpleados, 12, "Reporte de Empleados" + " --- " + F)**

   **System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)**

**BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CreadorReportes.RegistrosTerminados / CreadorReportes.CantidadRegistros * 100)**

4. Evento ProgressChanged de mi BackgroundWorker,aqui es donde le
   envio informacion a mi ProgressBar para que vaya cargandose.

   **FrmBarraProgreso.Guna2ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage**

   **FrmBarraProgreso.LblPorcentaje.Text = e.ProgressPercentage & "%"**
5. Evento RunWorkerCompleted de mi BackgroundWorker, aqui solo llamaria un MsgBox diciendo que el proceso de exportacion a sido exitoso.

Eso sería todo, agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: fijate si [esto que arme](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125788/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-optimizar-este-proceso-con-backgoundworker-c/125913#125913) alguna vez no te sirve. Igual asi como esta, tu pregunta es muy amplia... por ejemplo, no es lo mismo en wpf que en winforms... y tampoco queda claro si no entendes eventos o threads... porque si esta en el mismo o en otro no cambia nada...

Comment: Es que tengo un datagrid que se llena desde una base de datos y adicional un botón de exportar, al presionar el botón quiero que me salga un formulario de windows form con mi progressbar y posterior  a eso empiece hacer la tarea de exportación en segundo plano. No consigo que se muestre mi progresso y se queda congelando al rededor de 35 segundos en el proceso de exportación.

Comment: Y el codigo de todo eso para poder señalarte que estas haciendo mal?

Comment: @gbianchi Edité mi pregunta principal agregando mas detalle de mi código. A partir de la opción 3 no pude meter el código dentro de { } el sistema no me lo permitió, pero creo que se entiende.

Comment: No uses background worker.. usa async/await y no vas a tener problemas con las actualizaciones de pantalla...

Comment: Que pena... me podrías explicar como hacerlo? :'(

Comment: Esta en la pregunta que te relacione!!! la miraste???? el codigo ahi hace exactamente lo que vos queres, es un ejemplo de esto!

Comment: O sea, me olvido del BackGroundWorker y sus tres eventos y creo una funcion Asincrona de esta manera:  
Private Async Function Prueba1() As Task(Of Boolean)
    Await Task.Run(--aqui llamo la funcion generar reporte ---() 
    Thread.Sleep(10000))
     Return True
End Function`

Comment: Visual me salta error al usar Thread, me dice que  " 'Thread' no está declarado"

Comment: Hiciste el import correspondiente? vuelve a intentarlo, para actualizar la UI de la pantalla, necesitas llamarla con un invoke...

Comment: Cloné tu repositorio de GIT para ver mas detalles...

Comment: Me salta otro error: "La expresión no genera un valor"

Comment: No puedo ayudarte a arreglar codigo que no veo... de paso, si quieres, trabaja el codigo, y lo vemos por el [chat]... aca en el sitio no sirve

Comment: Gracias por tu valioso tiempo @gbianchi agradezco tu ayuda. :'/

Answer (score 0):

He probado realizarlo de esta forma

```
Private Async Sub BtnExportar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnExportar.Click

    Dim CargarReporte = New Task(Function()
                                     Dim FechaHoy As Date = Date.Now
                                     Dim F As String = Format(CDate(FechaHoy), "dd-MM-yyyy ( HH 'Hrs' mm 'Min' ss 'Seg' )")
                                     GenerarReporte(DgvEmpleados, 12, "Reporte de Empleados" + " --- " + F)
                                 End Function)

    CargarReporte.Start()
   

    Dim MostrarProgreso = New Task(Function()
                                       FrmBarraProgreso.Show()
                                       FrmBarraProgreso.Guna2ProgressBar1.Value = (CInt(CreadorReportes.CantidadRegistros / CreadorReportes.RegistrosTerminados * 100))
                                   End Function)
    MostrarProgreso.Start()
    Await MostrarProgreso

End Sub
```

No lo e logrado hacer me salta error en `FrmBarraProgreso.Guna2ProgressBar1.Value = (CInt(CreadorReportes.CantidadRegistros / CreadorReportes.RegistrosTerminados * 100))` que me dice:
*System.OverflowException: 'La operación aritmética ha provocado un desbordamiento.'*

Ya no se que mas hacer.

Solo quiero que al momento de  hacer la exportación salga mi barra de progreso cargando de acuerdo de cuantos registros se hayan completado para la exportación hasta llegar a 100%