# No se muestra el progreso del ProgressBar en C# - BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, windows-forms, progressbar

Tengo una Barra de Progreso pero no funciona, no me muestra su progreso mientras avanza mi proceso. Y lo que encontré de BackgroundWorker  me manda el mensaje y no me inicia ya la barra ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Mi proceso se ejecuta en varias ocasiones al darle a un botón de iniciar y ese se dirige a un timer ahí mando a llamar mi método que se ejecuta dependiendo de la fecha o parámetros que les de.

Estoy un poco revuelta , ya que es la primera vez q trabajo con windows form.

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

```
    private void Inicializar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                txtMensaje.Text = "";
                timerProceso.Start();
                bg.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                bg.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                bg.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
                bg.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
                bg.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
            }

    private void barraProgreso_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                timerProceso.Start();
            }

 

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                
                timerProceso.Start();
                
              
            }

 private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            BarraProgreso.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            lblTiempo.Text = BarraProgreso.Value.ToString() + "%";
}
 private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 

    RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                txtProceso.Text = "";
                txtMensaje.Text = "";
                MessageBox.Show("Completo...");
                    lblTiempo.Visible = false;
                    BarraProgreso.Visible = false;
                }
    
     private void timerProceso_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                bg.RunWorkerAsync();
                timerProceso.Enabled = false;
                DialogResult dresulConfirmacion = MessageBox.Show("Seguro que desea iniciar?", "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (dresulConfirmacion == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    DateTime ldatFechaActual = DateTime.Now;
                    
                    try
                    {
    string lstrFechaRegistro1 = ldatFechaInicio.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                            string lstrFechaRegistro2 = ldatFechaFin.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    
                            
                            using (WSDocumentoInvesdoc.ServiceClient wsRPA_Invesdoc = new WSDocumentoInvesdoc.ServiceClient())
                            {
                                
                                string lstrInvesdoc = wsRPA_Invesdoc.plistObtenerGuiasInvesdoc(lstrFechaRegistro1, lstrFechaRegistro2);
    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
                {
    }
```

Comment: Revisa mejor esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/125788/324) con su respuesta. Si puedes modernizar el proceso, sera mejor...

Comment: Y si editas tu pregunta con la respusta que te dieron, la respuesta se vuelve invalida. No lo hagas. SI tenes otra pregunta nueva, hacela en otra pregunta. Si la respuesta que te dieron te sirvio, aceptala.

Comment: rayos actualice y puse el mensaje de que lo habia actualizado pero creo no se guardo el mensaje , una disculpa.

Comment: Yo volvi atras tu actualizacin, porque si editas la pregunta con lo que tiene la respuesta, entonces parece que la respuesta no sirve, cuando la respuesta es justamente lo que contestaba la pregunta...

Comment: bueno en realidad sigue sin avanzar la barra de progreso

Answer (score 1):

En tu código, veo que estás usando un BackgroundWorker para realizar el proceso en segundo plano, y que estás manejando los eventos DoWork, ProgressChanged y RunWorkerCompleted. Sin embargo, no veo ningún código que indique cómo se está midiendo el progreso del proceso ni cómo se está actualizando la barra de progreso en consecuencia.

deberías agregar código en el evento DoWork que realice el proceso y, a medida que avance, informe el progreso al BackgroundWorker usando el método ReportProgress.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Realizar el proceso acá
    int progress = 0;
    while (progress < 100)
    {
        // Actualizar el progreso del proceso
        progress++;

        // Informar el progreso al BackgroundWorker
        bg.ReportProgress(progress);

        // Pausar el bucle durante unos milisegundos para simular el proceso
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Después, en el evento ProgressChanged, actualiza la barra de progreso con el porcentaje de progreso informado por el BackgroundWorker tal como ya lo estas haciendo.

Comment: am ahora me marca el mensaje cuando termina el proceso pero no me marca nada en la barra no aparece el progreso: BarraProgreso.Minimum = 0;
            BarraProgreso.Maximum = 100; y puse un if de porcentaje

Comment: OP actualizo su pregunta con este codigo.. mala mia...

Comment: como disculpe , igual puse que actualice con su codigo pero seguia sin marcarme el proceso , de hecho ya se ve pero cuando llega al proceso se pasma la barra y avanza hasta que termina,